# Line break in Text Area

Tags: php, textarea, line-breaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [line breaks in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480655/line-breaks-in-a-textarea)

I have a text area where the user inputs some description in paragraphs. Now I want that if the user wants to add two paragraph, he will press enter to add a line break. But when we store that value in database then that line break does not get saved.

I want to ask that if a user press enter to add a line break then it should also get saved in the database.

I m using php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use nl2br($content_here); while retrieving

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 5):

One line break should be a `<br />` and two should signify a paragraph break. So just look for your two `"\n\n"` statements in your code and replace all those with `</p><p>` and then just wrap `<p></p>` tags around the entire string.

Here's the series of steps that should take place:

1. Submit to your PHP server and set `$input = $_POST['input'];`
2. Do `$input = trim($input)` to remove all the extra linebreaks and whitespace from the start and end of the input.
3. Then do `$input = str_replace($input, "\n\n",'</p><p>');`
4. Then do `$input = '<p>' . $input . '</p>';`

---- EDIT ----

One final thing to keep in mind. If you do not want to have a bunch of empty `<p></p>` tags when If a user enters more than two consecutive linebreaks then you need to look out for that.

To get around that, do this instead.

```
$input = preg_replace("/\n(?:\n)+/",'</p><p>', $input)
//you may need to set the PHP PCRE multiline flag for this to work
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql_real_escape_string($input); This would probably save line feeds as well.