# Properly formatting a multiline textarea string in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this form, in it a textarea and a submit button. When you submit it, it queries whatever is in the textarea.

Here's that part of the code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['message']))
    {
        $EscMessage = $iDB->real_escape_string(rip_tags($_POST['message']));
        $EscName = $iDB->real_escape_string(rip_tags($_POST['subject'])); // rip_tags just strips HTML
        $Today = date("F j, Y, h:i:s A");

        $iDB->query("INSERT INTO `Match_Comments` (`URL`, `Name`, `Message`, `Date`) VALUES ('$EscMatch', '$EscName', '$EscMessage', '$Today')");
    }
```

That works fine and all, but if I write comments in the textarea like:

```
This is the message that I will be writting in the textarea

It includes multiple lines like right now.




And even large blocks of blank spaces.
```

Then when I query for the data, it shows ^ that message in 1 line without the blank lines. How can I fix this?

This is how it displays: ( But I want it just like it was written in the textarea )

> This is the message that I will be writting in the textarea It
>   includes multiple lines like right now. And even large blocks of blank
>   spaces.

Here's how I fetch the data:

```
$row['Message'];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [line breaks in a textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480655/line-breaks-in-a-textarea)

Comment: ALSO: Prepared Statements are your Friend: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.  IMHO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breakes in html are rendered as spaces. You should add a `<br />` where there is a line break.
Use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br).