# Add a line break to a html text area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I a trying to add a line break to a text area at run time (\n) but instead of displaying as a line break the text area physically puts in \n.
I have read various topics about this
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159622/jquery-textarea-append-newline-behavior) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480655/line-breaks-in-a-textarea) without any success.
It could be down to the way the data is updated within the text area but that shouldn't matter. My data is brought in through json from a php file and displayed through jQuery

Example of json response:

```
{"error":"2","err_msg":"","data":"<p class=\"left\">Aligned left text<\/p><br>Sub text <br>"}
```

The text in the text area should then display:

```
[left]Aligned left text[/left]
Sub text
```

But on my page I get

```
[left]Aligned left text[/left]\nSub text
```

I have php function to convert relevent html tags to what I want them but for some reason line breaks don't work

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('(\<p class="left"\>(.*?)\</p\>)is', function($matches){
   $txt = $matches[1];
   return '[left]'.$txt.'[/left]\n';
}, $string);

$string = str_replace('<br>','\n',$string);

die(json_encode(array('error' => '2', 'err_msg' => '', 'data' => $string)));
```

There is a lot more formatting and different tags but its only the line break that doesn't work.

This change should be display in a text area

```
$('#edit').val(json.data)
<textarea id="edit" ></textarea>
```

Comment: It looks like you're replacing the correct newline for HTML (<br>) with the incorrect one ('\n').

Comment: No same problem no line breaks it just displays <br> where I want the new line to start

Comment: Where you want to display the replaced string?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the HTML entities for line feed `&#10;` and carriage return `&#13;`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string literals encapsulated with apostrophes, try:

`$string = str_replace("<br>", "\n", $string)`

There is a significant difference between `'this string'` and `"this string"` in PHP; using apostrophes to encapsulate your string in PHP will treat `\n` literally as `\n` rather than `chr(10)`.