# How to preserve line breaks in textarea?

Tags: php, html

I went through similar questions on this issue but couldn't find a solution.
I have a simple textarea in which text will be pasted or entered directly.

How do I preserve those line breaks?

Right now line breaks will just be ignored, but when I `print_r($_POST)` and inspect the output in the Chrome Developer Console it still has the original text breaks. 
How can I display those when showing the submitted data?

Comment: Replace newlines with `<br>`s?

Comment: `<pre>`....`</pre>` ?

Answer (score 1):

> Right now line breaks will just be ignored

No, it is still there. The key you miss is that what you enter goes as ASCII code `LF` (`0xA`) but this makes no effect in HTML unless the text is displayed as preformatted block (`<pre> ... </pre>). If not, then line break is represented by`
`tag so what you need to do if you want to display entered text is to convert`LF`s to`
`(you can use`nl2br()`function to do that) or use`` block.

Answer (score 1):

As Marcin noted, use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) when displaying your data as instructed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6480671/6206601

Comment: An example - much better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nl2br()` function:

> Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

```
echo(nl2br($_POST));
```

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php.