# Textarea doesn't count new lines in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I have a `textarea` that takes some strings that user gave it and post it to another PHP file to save in into DB.

The process works completely fine but when I extract what user typed in the `textarea` from my DB the text shows without the enters / breaks that user give in the `textarea` before.

For example, if the user writes:

```
'hi guys 
my name is '
```

it shows when i extract it like this:

```
'hi guys my name is'
```

Where is the enter that I put in first place?

How can I fix this it doesn't work on either Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: can you provide code what you have done?

Comment: Please at least post the code of how you save your data and how you're outputting it

Comment: guys i'm using laravel i extract it normally :

Comment: Possible duplicate of [line breaks in a textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480655/line-breaks-in-a-textarea)

Comment: Take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br) like below:

```
echo nl2br("hi guys my name is");
```

Comment: yeah it works but appears as a normal text in the body of the page

Comment: like 'hi guys <br /> my name is'