# proper method to print \r\n as newline in textarea value

Tags: php, html

I have a string stored in a database like `hello, \r\n how are you? \r\n`. I want to print this string in textarea to edit the text. Which is the appropriate method to print new line in textarea instead of `\r\n` ? I have tried `nl2br(str_replace('\r\n', '\n', $str));` but it will print `\n` as it is. I got my result by using

```
<?php echo str_replace ('\\', '' ,str_replace('<br />', PHP_EOL, str_replace('\r\n', '<br />', $str))); } ?>
```

Another solution I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480655/line-breaks-in-a-textarea) is

`str_replace('\r\n', '&#10;', $str);`

But can anyone tell me what is `&#10;`. It seems `HTML Entity Number`. But I don't know what is it actually.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace \r & \n with <br/>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946114/how-to-replace-r-n-with-br)

Comment: `nl2br(str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $str));` ... or just `str_replace('\r\n', '<br />', $str));` maybe? Assuming you have quite literally got the character sequence `\r\n` in the database...

Comment: Read about PHP [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). [`'\r\n'`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) is not the same as [`"\r\n"`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: @CD001 have you tried the change you suggest? It doesn't work.

Comment: @axiac - depends on what's coming out of the database. I did specify assuming it's literally the character sequence `\r\n` (rather than `CRLF`)

Comment: @CD001 that solution is not working for me. what I get in textarea is `hello, <br /> how are you? <br />` .

Comment: Ah - so you *do* literally have `\r\n` coming from the database then... in which case it should probably be something like `<textarea><?= str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $str); ?></textarea>` (I thought `textarea` parsed html tags for some reason...)

Comment: `str_replace('\r\n', '&#10;', $str);` this is also working. But can anyone tell me what is  `&#10;` . It seems ` HTML Entity Number`. But I don't know what is it actually.

Comment: @CD001 `str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $str);` is worked. can you please explain more why `nl2br(str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $str));`  did not worked?

Comment: `&#10;` is the HTML entity code for the *line feed* character (ASCII 10); so that would be `"\n"` in a PHP string (note, not `'\n'` the quote types for PHP strings are important)... as for `nl2br(str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $str));` that should work **but** would insert `<br />` tags before each new line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165706/discussion-between-softech-and-cd001).